# IF versus IIF, y Columns.Contains() diferencia en la lógica de evaluación vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Quedaré muy agradecido si alguien puede orientarme indicandome por qué la función **IIF** y **Table.Contains()** generan este error; el caso es que estoy recorriendo columnas en un DataTable para capturar valores unicamente si vienen las columnas conocidas, pero el metodo "Contains" pareciera fallar dentro del **IIF**, pues en un **if** normal no falla.

- El error que me devuelve es: "La columna Nombre no existe en el DataTable" y es exactamente lo que pretendo controlar validando si existe o no la columna antes de tomar el dato. Provocando que se detenga la ejecución en el caso que no esté la columna y no me devuelve "0".

Genera error lo siguiente:

```
Dim p_Nombre As String
...
p_Nombre = IIf((Tabla.Columns.Contains("Nombre") = True), (tabla.Rows(J).Item("Nombre").ToString), "0")
```

Pero **no** genera error para el siguiente:

```
Dim p_Nombre As String
...
p_Nombre = IIf((Tabla.Columns.Contains("Nombre") = True), "1", "0")
```

Si sabemos que:

```
x = iif( evaluacion, valor-caso-true, valor-caso-false)
```

¿Porqué evalua el caso false?

**Mil gracias por cualquier orientación**

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Es un error tipografico? Tabla.Columns.Contains("Nombre") = True), (tabla.Rows(J).Item("Nombre") esas dos tabla son distintas (una es mayuscula y la otra minuscula)???

Comment: Debes añadir el código donde declaras y llenas las variables `Tabla` y `J` para poder saber que es lo que está fallando. Comprueba que la tabla tiene datos depurando el código y edita la pregunta añadiendo las pruebas que has hecho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Estimados colegas he encontrado la respuesta y les comparto:**

Se debe a que Vb.net evalúa los operadores ternarios en caso true y false. Por lo tanto toca castear el valor de tipo object que retorna la iif. No hay que olvidar que se trata de una Function, lo que hace que ésta pierda el encanto.

**La solucion:** Al parecer a partir de la version 9 de VB.net han resuelto el tema saltandose un poco el estilo de la sintaxis tradicional y asemejandola a C# con lo siguiente:

```
Dim Respuesta1 as Integer = if(a > b ? a , b)
Dim Respuesta2 As Integer = If(100 > 52, (10 / 5), (1 / 0))
```

Espero les sirva este aporte.